# Mono.Android reference in PCL project in VS 2017 Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have created a project in Visual Studio 2017 Windows. Now I am trying to work on it from Mac. While tried to build the project I can see reference to Mono.Android is not available. Also System.ComponentModel is unavailable. How I can add the reference for both of it?
[image]

Comment: You need to remove the reference to the `Mono.Android` as it should not be referenced in a NetStd/PCL library. If you need access to Android native features in a library, create a `Xamarin.Android` library project, not a NetStd/PCL-based one.

Comment: If it is working fine in windows. It should work on Mac as well.

Comment: Just because it "works" in Windows does not mean it is correctly implemented. NetStd/PCL libraries are designed to be platform independent and thus you are hack'ing a NetStd/PCL library to become a Mono.Android based library which will cause you problems (as you are just starting to see). I assume your NetStd/PCL code is directly referencing native Android features and if that is what you really need, create a Xamarin.Android based library and copy your native code to it. FYI: Also this library, as it is, will not be able to be used in a Xamarin.iOS project without more build issues

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same issue mono.android is missing, finally it work by adding mono.android.dll. I did something like this in my project, in Deploy.cs file add this line

```
class Deploy
{
    [Android.Runtime.Register("getExternalStoragePublicDirectory", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/File;", "")]
```

it show missing mono.android.dll library is missing need to add into the project. Problem solved later I comment this line.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture above you can see that the reference is made to a particular file on your Windows computer which on the Mac is obviously not on that path. If you want to make the project work you should find those files on the Mac and reference them. Copying them from Windows somewhere and referencing them should work too.

But as people noted, the point of PCL project is not to contain references like this so whole the architecture of your app is wrong and that's why you see the problems. So you may want to resolve the root of the problem as this probably won't be the last thing that you encounter by doing the things in the wrong way.